# Griffon / Groovy programming error : don't understand

Tags: groovy, griffon

I've rewritten this question as i've localized the problem but don't understand it  ..

I'm experimenting with Griffon  ..  In a view class I had some code  ..

```
new Timer(1000, { e ->
    controller.countDown()
} as ActionListener).start()
```

which works fine (it drives a countdown clock on the corresponding view so i'm not certain its the correct place to put it .. but it works)

I moved the code to the controller in the corresponding controllers mvcGroupInit routine and got an error .. so i changed the implementation to Java ..

```
Timer myTimer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
      void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //countDown()
            println "Mmm ? "
        }
} )
```

and I get an error ..

```
2014-10-08 10:13:46,695 [main] INFO  griffon.swing.SwingApplication - Initializing all startup   groups: [sequenceMonitor]
2014-10-08 10:13:49,391 [main] ERROR griffon.util.GriffonExceptionHandler - Uncaught Exception
groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for:     java.util.Timer(java.lang.Integer, sequencemonitor.SequenceMonitorController$1)
at sequencemonitor.SequenceMonitorController.mvcGroupInit(SequenceMonitorController.groovy:36)
```

which points to

```
   Timer myTimer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
        void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { ....
```

So I copied the code into the groovy console ..

```
import java.awt.event.*

new Timer(1000, {e->
   println "running .." 
} as ActionListener).start()
```

and ran it .. got

```
WARNING: Sanitizing stacktrace:

    groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: java.util.Timer(java.lang.Integer, com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12)

at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeConstructor(MetaClassImpl.java:1550)

at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeConstructor(MetaClassImpl.java:1404)

at  org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.MetaClassConstructorSite.callConstructor(MetaClassConstructorSit e.java:46)

at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:57)

at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:182)

at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:194)

at ConsoleScript9.run(ConsoleScript9:3)
```

I dont understand why  Groovy is objecting . Can someone enlighten me  ??  Also is this a reasonable place to put this kind of timer given it updates a model which is reflected in the UI  ..

I'm using Griffon 1.4 / Java 1.7 / .. 
Thanks again  ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the wrong `Timer` class (by default): `java.util.Timer` is there because everything from `java.util` is imported automatically in groovy.  Use instead a FQN:

```
 new javax.swing.Timer(1000, ...
```